# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded - tkinter timer project

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I'm somewhat of a beginner in Python and I'm not familiar with this. I'm working on a timer project where I'd make a loop until my number of seconds has reached 0, but I always get this error.

This is the function (working with tkinter):

```
def sec():
    second -= 1

def eg_number():
    root.after(1000, sec)
    eg_number()
    if second == 0:
        return  #even with this, I still get the error
```

I also tried setting my recursion limit and it still wont work. I just get a stack overflow.

Comment: this is infinite loop of calling eg_number() over and over again

Comment: If `sec` is actually the code as you've given it, then it's not being run, because it would immediately error.

Comment: Even if you manage change it to exit when `second` reaches zero, it's still not sensible to invoke infinite recursion until a time limit expires. It serves no purpose and will always cause a stack overflow. What you're trying to do does not make sense.

Comment: Do you have any solutions? Consider the comment below, from the user Or Y. Thanks for answering.

Comment: The solution is for you not to try and perform unbounded recursion until a time limit expires. Since you give no indication of why you are hoping to achieve, it's hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `second` should be declared as global inside `sec()` function.  Also you should pass `eg_number` to `after()` instead:

```
second = 20

def sec():
    global second
    second -= 1
    print(second)

def eg_number():
    sec()
    if second == 0:
        return
    root.after(1000, eg_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep calling eg_number inside of eg_number with now stop condition.
move the `if second == 0` before that call to eg_number

```
def eg_number():
    root.after(1000, sec)
    if second == 0:
        return
    eg_number()
```

Comment: Still have the same problem